# wcf service on mobile 5.0

Tags: wcf, windows-mobile

I have writed a primitive wcf (vs 2010) service and created proxy files by svcutil. Later I created a mobile project on vs2008 and added proxy files on project but this error occured.

Error   1   The type or namespace name 'ServiceContractAttribute' does not exist in the namespace 'System.ServiceModel' (are you missing an assembly reference?)    C:\Users\Abb\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\WCF\MobileService\MobileClient\Sample.cs

the proxy files runs well on console application (vs 2008) but there is errors on mobile.

System.ServiceModel doesnot support ServiceContractAttribute.

Answer (score 2):

For mobile applications you shouldn’t use SvcUtil to generate proxies since this does not generate code compatible with the subset of WCF functionality available to the .NET Compact Framework on mobile devices.

Instead, you should use NetCFSvcUtil.exe. See this link for more information: [Using NetCFSvcUtil.exe to interact with ServiceContracts](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/danhorbatt/archive/2007/09/12/using-compact-svcutil-to-interact-with-servicecontracts.aspx)

Comment: I have path for SLSvcUtil.exe. But can't find NetCFSvcUtil.exe where it is located?